# Bootstrap Cards not clickable

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a column of cards like :

```
<div className="col-4" >   
 <div className="card" style={{width: "17vw", padding: "3%", cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={()=>{window.location.href=`/profile/${this.state.user._id}`}}>
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <center> <img src={profile} style={{height: "6vw"}} /></center>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="card" style={{width: "17vw",  padding: "3%", cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={()=>{window.location.href=`/dashboard/${this.state.user._id}`}}>
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <center> <img src={dashboard} style={{height: "6vw"}} /></center>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="card" style={{width: "17vw",  padding: "3%", border: "#FBDE11 3px solid", cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={()=>{window.location.href=`/clients/${this.state.user._id}`}} >
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <center> <img src={clients} style={{height: "6vw"}} /></center>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

However, The cursor is neither becoming pointer nor is it clickable for the bottom 2 cards. Its working only for the first card. What exactly is the problem here and how do I fix it?

Comment: you no need to use {} curley braces in the inline style and javascript.

Comment: ReactJS requires it

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, ref this link for how to ask questions, your questions should be clear what are you asking.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Don't use `<center>`; it's obsolete.

Comment: But how does it work for the first card but not the other two cards?